# Performance - Iterating in Java vs Querying the database

Tags: java, database, lambda, iterator

It's difficult for me to think how to ask this so I will create an example to demonstrate what I am asking for:

Suppose I have my model:

```
public class UserEvaluation {
    String name;
    Date respondedAt;
}

public class Evaluation {
    String name;
    List<UserEvaluation> userEvaluations;
{
```

And then in my EvaluationService I need to know the amount of userEvaluations which have been responded (`respondedAt != null`).

Possible solutions:

**1 By iterating through all the items:**

```
Evaluation evaluation = evaluationRepository.get(1);

Long count = 0;

for(UserEvaluation userEvaluation : evaluation.getUserEvaluations()) {
    if(userEvaluation.getRespondedAt() != null) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

**2 By Lambda Expressions:**

```
Evaluation evaluation = evaluationRepository.get(1);

Long count = evaluation.getUserEvaluations().stream()
                  .filter(ue -> ue.getRespondedAt() != null)
                  .count();
```

**3 By querying de database:**

```
Evaluation evaluation = evaluationRepository.get(1);

Long count  = userEvaluationRepository.getRespondedCountByEvaluation(evaluation); //And implement this simple count query.
```

So this is the simpliest thing. Which I would pick? I'm using a lot of iterators and lambda stream iterator expressions in my app. But I am worried about that should be an error and I would need to interact more with the database? Should I? Should I not?

Comment: Filtering on the DB side will be more efficient, and you don't have to retrieve a whole bunch of data that you don't need .

Answer (score 0):

If you are not sure I would design it so you can change it as required. Have a DAO implementation which accesses the database, but one which could be changed to use in memory data if you determine using the database is not fast enough.

```
interface DatabaseDAO {
    long getRespondedCountByEvaluation(Evaluation e);
}
```

It depends on which approach would retrieve less data. If you grab the data once and extract information from that many times it can be faster, but if you are only getting a small portion each time and have an indexed database it can be much faster.  I would design it

Comment: Yeah but, this question does not have to do with abstraction. I understand your point, but the question is about which to prefer or how or why decide to implement one or another, despite of the abstraction.

Comment: @FernandoFradegrada The answer is; it depends on your use case. You decide by trying them and seeing how they perform for your use case. In some cases, it will be obvious that you need to cache the data or not as mentioned. If you don't have any profiling information, go with the simplest implementation.